# Sql table value with markup into a number?

Tags: php, sql, substr, strpos

I have a database price entry that looks like

```
<b>14.75€</b>
```

and I need php to return it as:
1) 14.75
2) 14 and 75 separately (another function I've figured out turns the pre-decimal number to words)

I think the cents can be separated by something like this

```
$final1 = substr($vtotal, strpos($vtotal, '.')+3);
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`$final1 = explode('.', $vtotal);`

`$final1` is now an array.

`$final[0] = 14`

`$final[1] = 75`

Finally...

Currency's aren't an integer, they're a float, so we cast it to a float and then replace the occurrence of the euro symbol.

`$clean = (float)preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/ui','',$vtotal);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$money = (float) '14.75€'; //To 14.75
list($int, $cent) = explode('.', (string)$money);

print (int)$cent; //int 75
```